# CSS How to rotate an image with fulcrum (anchor point)

Tags: html, css

I can't explain this problem any better, so let me give an analogy.

I have a line like this:

```
___________
```

what I want to do is rotate it in any degrees but the left side is anchored. So when I rotate it, it moves just like clock arms (fulcrum on left side). is this achievable using css? sorry for the dumb question, I really don't know how to do it.

I appreciate your answers, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Is an  representing the angle of the rotation. The direction of rotation depends on the writing direction. In a left-to-right context, a positive angle denotes a clockwise rotation, a negative angle a counter-clockwise one. In a right-to-left context, a positive angle denotes a counter-clockwise rotation, a negative angle a clockwise one.